# How to calculate profit using aggregations from two collections in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections, orders and producttypes

ProductTypes:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 609d79de5909592f2635c64e, 
    "name" : "T-Shirt", 
    "subType" : "Round Neck", 
    "__v" : 0, 
    "size" : "XXL", 
    "sellingPrice" : 320, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-05-18T05:22:00.695+0000"), 
    "actualPrice" : 200, 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-05-25T12:11:50.986+0000")
},
{ 
    "_id" : 609d79de5909592f2635c64d, 
    "name" : "T-Shirt", 
    "subType" : "V Neck", 
    "__v" : 0, 
    "size" : "XXL", 
    "sellingPrice" : 290, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-05-18T05:22:00.695+0000"), 
    "actualPrice" : 200, 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-05-25T12:11:50.986+0000")
}
```

Orders:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "60a63e369cf3a806c0209bd8", 
    "items" : [
        {
            "type" : "609d79de5909592f2635c64e", 
            "quantity" : 1, 
            "sellingPrice" : 320
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "609d79de5909592f2635c64d", 
            "quantity" : 2, 
            "sellingPrice" : 290
        }
    ], 
    "orderId" : "ORD101", 
    "from" : "Abc", 
    "to" : "xyz", 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-05-20T10:47:18.920+0000"), 
    "__v" : 0, 
    "tracking" : "12345678"
}
```

I want to calculate total profit per order like:

```
{orderId: "ORD101", createdAt: ISODate("2021-05-18T05:22:00.695+0000"), profit: 300}
```

I don't know how to join these two collections to calculate the profit.

But I tried something like below in node:

```
Order.aggregate([{
        $unwind: '$items'
    }, {
        $project: {
            orderId:1,
            quantity: "$items.quantity",
            sellingPrice: {
                $multiply: [
                    {"$ifNull": ["$items.quantity", 0]},
                    {"$ifNull": ["$items.price", 0]}
                ]
            },
            type: '$items.type'
        }
        }])
    .exec(function(err, transactions) {
        //console.log(transactions);
        ProductType.populate(transactions,{path: 'type',  select: 'actualPrice' }, function(err, populatedTransactions) {
            //res.json(populatedTransactions);
            var items = [];
            var totalProfit = 0;
            if(populatedTransactions){
                populatedTransactions.forEach( order => {
                    if( order.quantity != undefined && order.sellingPrice != undefined && order.sellingPrice > 0){
                        let profit = order.sellingPrice - (order.quantity * order.type.actualPrice);
                        totalProfit = totalProfit + profit;
                        items.push({ orderId: order.orderId, profit: profit });
                    }
                })
                res.status(200).json({data: items, totalProfit: totalProfit});
            }
        });
    });
```

Is this the right way?

Here am using `$unwind` on the array then populating with producttypes collection to get an actual price, then am doing calculations to get the profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$project` to show required fields
- `$unwind` deconstruct the `items` array
- `$lookup` with `productTypes` collection
- calculate the profit

  - `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from item `actualPrice` result
  - `$subtract` `sellingPrice` by `actualPrice`
  - `$multiply` above result with `quantity`
- `$group` by order `_id` and get required fields and sum `profit`

```
Order.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      orderId: 1,
      createdAt: 1,
      items: 1
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "productTypes", // replace your actual collection name
      localField: "items.type",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "item"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      profit: {
        $multiply: [
          {
            $subtract: [
              "$items.sellingPrice",
              { $arrayElemAt: ["$item.actualPrice", 0] }
            ]
          },
          "$items.quantity"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      orderId: { $first: "$orderId" },
      createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
      profit: { $sum: "$profit" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hnvdmQqem3X)

Comment: Thanks for fast reply and the solution. But the problem is in the play ground it is working fine, but in my system $lookup's "item" is coming as empty array, is that an issue with my mongo version? Here are my mongo version details MongoDB shell version v4.4.5
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.5",
    "gitVersion": "ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "system",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}

Comment: no it is not mongo version issue, can you confirm the `items.type` field in orders is string type or object id type?

Comment: it is objectId  "items" : [
        {
            "type" : ObjectId("609d79de5909592f2635c64d"), 
            "quantity" : NumberInt(0), 
            "price" : NumberInt(0)
        }
    ]

Comment: ok so i don't see any problem if its objectid.

Comment: I removed group from above code then it is giving profit as null

Comment: yes you are saying lookup does not give anything then ofcourse the profit will be null, confirm `from: "productTypes"` collection name, that I have mentioned in comment.

Comment: after using $addFields: {
      "items.type": {
        $toObjectId: "$items.type"
      }
    }  lookup is giving the producttypes, but after doing calculations it is giving profit as null. I already changed my collection name.

Comment: check the field name everywere in profile calculation $addFields,

Comment: Thank you so much @turivishal, mistake is from my side, i renamed one field, now it is giving proper result. thank you very much for quick solutions.